# What would be a right behavior to put a tea spoon?

Tags: behavior

I have a mild cerebral palsy that I can't carry a cup of tea to the table I eat. Therefore the worker of the coffee lounge carries my the cup to the table. He puts a spoon on it but there is no saucer. But I have read that at least in Finland where I work, it is bad behavior to drink something such that there is a spoon on the cup. But in this case, should I put the spoon on the table or hold it on my another hand?

Comment: I think most (if not all) people will not mind either way. Better things to worry about. Also if that know you have a problem they should be a lot more tolerant

Comment: Ask the worker to bring you a saucer?

Comment: The main reason for taking the spoon out of the cu is so you don't poke your eye with it. A secondary reason is that it's possible that you might tilt the cup to an angle where the spoon falls, which could be a bit messy. If you aren't worried about that, and aren't dining with billionaires and heads of state, I would advise doing whatever works best for you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a general etiquette question, not related to the workplace.

Answer (score 5):

I am not in Finland, but I think no one will mind either way. My guess is that your source saying it is "bad behavior" to drink with a spoon in the cup is discussing "proper" formal etiquette, which really only applies to formal events and dinners, if that. Sitting in your office, most of your coworkers probably won't even nontice or care. So leave the spoon in the cup, or put it on the table, or hold it in your hand - it's really up to you. The only thing I would suggest is that if you do put it on the table, make sure to use a napkin or wipe up any liquid on the table.

Answer (score 1):

It is bad etiquette to drink with it in the cup as well as being a bit unsanitary to put the teaspoon on the desk.

I'd ask politely for a saucer, failing that I'd put the spoon on a piece of paper if I had nothing better.

Neither holding it in my hand nor drinking the tea with it still in the cup appeal to me, but that could be just a personal quirk. In your situation I would probably have a small container on my desk for it in the same way I have one for my pens and another for loose objects like screws and screw drivers I'm using.

At the end of the day though, this is just to make you comfortable with it. If you'd rather just leave it in the cup, then do so. Your condition is obviously known, and I can't see anyone holding something so small against you.